# How Can I install OctoberCMS with PHP Version 5.x?

Tags: php, octobercms

I have Windows 10, Xampp installed with PHP Version 5.x and I want to install OctoberCMS with Installation wizard https://octobercms.com/docs/setup/installation but I noticed that OctoberCMS requires **PHP 7.0** or higher to achieve this and I have **version 5.x**.

So How can I install OctoberCMS with **PHP Version 5.x** ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK Guys, Eventually I have come up with the solution to install **OctoberCMS** with PHP Version 5.x.

Remember, these steps can be varied based on your operating system and the things which you have installed in your system.

- First go to OctoberCMS Change log -
  https://octobercms.com/changelog and find *Build 419* has the php
  version 5.x support.
- Then go to OctoberCMS release list - https://github.com/octobercms/october/releases and click on the version you need to install which is *v1.0.419*. Install the zip to the root of xampp/htdocs and extract the folder.
- Then inside the same folder which extracted, run  this `composer install`.
- After this, run `php artisan october:env` .. You can run `C:\xampp\php\php.exe artisan october:env` if you are having an error **php is not recognized as an internal or external command**.
- After  `php artisan october:env`, `.env` file is created. There you need to modify your database settings like database name, port (put 3306 for localhost etc) by opening this file which will be in same folder.
- Then run `php artisan october:up` or `C:\xampp\php\php.exe artisan october:up`. It will create database tables and your admin user will be created with User: **admin**, Password: **admin** (You can change this after logging IN). And backend url will be something like http://example.com/backend.
- Once its done, you can cut paste all your extracted folder files to root .. like from `C:\xampp\htdocs\youproject\version419` to `C:\xampp\htdocs\youproject\`.

Hope this helps.