# Parse error: syntax error on newly installed October CMS using installer.php

Tags: laravel, installation, octobercms

I just installed October CMS using their installer.php, afterwards, after setting up my database and admin, I get this

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 101
```

Comment: Which PHP version are you running?

Comment: It was recently 5.4 in my hosting, then I followed instructions and upgraded it to 7.0. I verified using phpinfo.php

Comment: Not sure what went wrong here with PHP Version 7.0 as you have not mentioned any other environment details. But if you want to install OctoberCMS with php version 5.4 or below then follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483260/how-can-i-install-octobercms-with-php-version-5-x