# October CMS unable to load dashboard, attach project nor install plugin

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I have just done a fresh installation of OctoberCMS. in the Backend, Dashboard shows the loader turning forever and I go to settings trying to attach project, the background blur, loader pops up for 0.1sec then nothing happen, background remains blur nothing i could do but refresh. I reinstall the whole thing and try again, same problem happens. Also, I am unable to install any plugins.

Any Idea on what is going on?

Comment: can you share your `chrome dev tool inspector`  errors or network errors

Comment: @HardikSatasiya I would like to but it happens to have no error at all on inspector

Comment: hmm, `network tab`, `ajax-request logs`

Comment: @HardikSatasiya hm.. I am unsure how to check ajax-request logs, but in the network tab there doesn't seem to have bug or error shown.

Comment: my skype `hardik_satasiya` can we talk and share your url and details so i can look up for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, after testing(teamviewer) all stuff it seems its `php version` issue its `5.6`

> https://octobercms.com/docs/setup/installation

according to guide it needs `PHP 7.0` or up

so you need to `update php` version to `PHP 7.0` and then you can try again it will work surely :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just missed on the requirement. This is of big help to me thanks a lot for your effort Hardik

Comment: This is good answer, if you want to install OctoberCMS with PHP version 5.x here is my answer how I dealt with it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483260/how-can-i-install-octobercms-with-php-version-5-x hope this helps too. Thanks